# Bash scripts handled differently then typing in the terminal?

Tags: macos, bash

I'm having some problems with bash scripting. I want the script to find the "Firefox.app" directory, but things that work when I type them in the shell interpreter don't work in the script.

```
ffxapp=`find /Applications/ -name "Firefox.app" -print | tee firefox.location`
```

When I type that into the shell, it works `($ffxapp == "/Applications/Firefox.app")`. In a script, it doesn't `($ffxapp == "")`. I am so confused.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? What is the actual effect when you run this in a script?

Comment: Beware of leaving files (called firefox.location) scattered around the landscape.   What do you have in the script's shebang line?  `#!/bin/bash` or something else?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash`, and the script is localized to its own folder, so I thought it was probably ok.

Comment: You should use an absolute path for your output file. If you don't, the file will be created in the current directory, not the directory where the script is. What happens if you add `echo "$ffxapp"` as the next line in your script? Also, try removing the pipe to `tee` to see if that has any effect (it shouldn't).

Comment: I already tried both of thouse, before posting the question. For now I've simply added `ffxapp=/Applications/Firefox.app` and am going to assume that it will always be there. I'm tired of this script.

Comment: Could you post the entire script and exactly how you run it?

Answer (score 2):

Let me turn my telepathic mode on. The most probable cause of your problem is that you are assigning a variable in the script and expect it to appear in your shell when you are checking for it. However, when script is ran by a shell, it creates a sub-shell so all variables declared there are not exposed to the environment of a parent shell. If you want to export a variable from the script, you have to explicitly tell the bash to run it in the same shell. OK, too much words, here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

FOO=bar
```

When you run this script, FOO variable will not appear in your shell even if you use "export":

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

FOO=bar

$ ./test.sh 
$ echo $FOO

$
```

But if you run it using "source" command, it will work:

```
$ source ./test.sh 
$ echo $FOO
bar
$
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Vlad's answer, by adding an `echo $FOO` *in* the script you can see the value is there when the script is running, but gone when the script has terminated:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

FOO=bar
echo $FOO

$ ./test.sh
bar
$ echo $FOO

$
```